# Element vertical alignment right after its top element strictly floating from left to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

How to force elements to fall right under its top element floating from left if width of box is static but height can vary.
Bootstrap after droping element to next line put it right under the element with the smallest height. That makes gaps vertically between elements.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class=col-lg-2></div>
 <div class=col-lg-2></div>
 <div class=col-lg-2></div>
    ...
</div>
```

But i want it to float always from left to right as its specified in `image`
May it be done using pure css?

[image]

Comment: If you build columns instead of rows, then you can do it with CSS. http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/ There are also some cool plugins that do it, like masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: For mobile display are you wanting it too list 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9... or is it okay to go 1 6 11 2 7 12 3 8 13 4 9 14 5 10 15?

Comment: Problem here is that building blocks by columns would ruin the horizontal float and therefore an order. Which would require to add logic for order.